# Slim framework v4 -- Add globals to TwigView

Tags: php, twig, slim

In testing, I have been unable to add globals to Slim v4's TwigView. It used to be that you could do it like so:

```
$twigView->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container->get('flash'));
$twigView->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);
```

But that now throws the exception: Unable to add global 'flash' as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized.

I took a look at the Environment class of Twig and found this bit of validation:

```
 /**
 * Registers a Global.
 *
 * New globals can be added before compiling or rendering a template;
 * but after, you can only update existing globals.
 *
 * @param string $name  The global name
 * @param mixed  $value The global value
 */
public function addGlobal($name, $value)
{
    if ($this->extensionSet->isInitialized() && !array_key_exists($name, $this->getGlobals())) {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Unable to add global "%s" as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized.', $name));
    }

    if (null !== $this->resolvedGlobals) {
        $this->resolvedGlobals[$name] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->globals[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why we seem to be throwing the exception if the global DOESN'T exist, instead of if it DOES exist? That seems to be a logic error to me, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a logical error.

From the DocBlock you posted with your question:

> New globals can be added before compiling or rendering a template; but after, you can only update existing globals.

Now having a look at the code:

```
if (
    // if the extension is initialized, the right side of && operator will be evaluated and...
    $this->extensionSet->isInitialized() &&
    // ...this means, we are only allowed to UPDATE a global,
    // so the global should already exist
    // and its lack of existence is an error, hence, if it does not exists, we throw an exception
    !array_key_exists($name, $this->getGlobals())

) {
    throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Unable to add global "%s" as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized.', $name));
}
```

The error text basically says:

> A global with the name you're referring to **does not exist**, which means this is not an update but a creation operation, 
>   and since the extension is already initialized, you're not allowed to do an update.

Comment: Hmmm, well then the question becomes: How exactly, and WHERE, does one add globals to the Slim 4 TwigView? It seems to be broken somewhere, as anytime I attempt it I get the "Unable to add global as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized." error.

Comment: You should let the readers know how you attempted to add a global, so maybe we'll be able to help. I suggest updating the question and adding the relevant part of your code. For now, I can suggest you to try to add globals  _before_ creating a new TwigMiddleware.